# Where to find high-quality icon sets?

Tags: icon

I'd like to change the style of our Windows Mobile application to follow the Modern UI style (as in Windows 8 or Windows Phone 7). While there are excellent guidelines for layout, fonts and sizes, I'm not able to find suitable icons to use in our toolbar (little images showing the state of the network or the battery). Those are the flaws of the icon packs I already found:

- Usually there are just one or two battery icons, whereas I need several
  to indicate the different states
- The icons get very blurry when resized to 16x16 pixels (even for vector graphics)
- A lot of icon sets contain gradients, shadows or gray pixels
- Most of the icon sets contain only a hundred to five hundred icons

If you have a look at the [icons used by Windows Phone 7](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/basics/what-do-the-icons-on-my-phone-mean), they're very clear and sharp. I already know [Syncfusion Metro Studio](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio), but the icons get very blurry when resized to 16x16 pixels as well. Currently we're using the icons from [IconExperience](http://www.iconexperience.com/), but they don't provide suitable icons for Modern UI applications.

So my question is basically: Where can I find professional, high-quality icon packs with a lot of different icons (either PNG or vector graphics)? They don't have to be free, but must be allowed to be used for commercial applications. What are the major icons vendors and what platforms are available to obtain icon packs from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Icon Finder](http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=windows%20mobile) is like Google image search for icon hunting.

[Icon Factory](http://iconfactory.com/stockicons) has a lot of stock but they also provide custom services.

If you really want good stuff, pay someone to make them specifically for your app. A good UI designer goes a long way toward building a brand.

Your question got me digging around IconFinder for the first time in a while. I found [this set which seems to answer your concerns](http://modernuiicons.com/).

Comment: I tested a lot of icon packs today (thanks for the Icon Factory link btw) and finally decided to hire someone to create the icons for the status bar.

Comment: Good call, Gene. It's the best way to go if you want a unified UI.

Answer (score 5):

For the Win8 aesthetic, the first thing that comes to mind is the Noun Project:

http://thenounproject.com/

Answer (score 2):

Just to quickly reaffirm the answers above: [Icon Finder](https://www.iconfinder.com/) and [The Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/) are both fantastic resources.

Here are a few more to consider:

- [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/) - one part a web-font generator for icon files (turns vector SVG's into fonts) and one part a searchable library of free-to-use and CC font libraries. Definitely worth scouting around. Check out [their library](http://icomoon.io/app/#library).
- Similar to the above link, [Fontello](http://fontello.com/) is a pretty big listing of icon fonts, along with their license types.
- A popular icon maker is [DutchIcon](http://dutchicon.com/stock-icons#&1&popularity), their Gizmo icon family feels fairly Windows 8 Inspired, though it's a bit more rounded/thicker strokes. That being said, I generally find them to work well with the big, colored blocks in the Metro style.
- Kind of random, but looking through Dribbble for icon freebies can result in some really nice icon sets. I've found that [psddd](http://psddd.co/category/icons_5.html) does a good job at finding free resources to use.

Answer (score 1):

Let me list some newer icon packs. All of them are open source:

- https://material.io/icons/ - original Google's one, 900 icons
- https://materialdesignicons.com/ - a guy called Andrew extended it to 2000 icons
- http://fontawesome.io/ - Industry standard!
- https://icons8.com/line-awesome - An alternative with a slightly
  different style
- https://iconpharm.com/ - bunch of other open source icon packs